# Logging in website with scrapy without the login file

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrap the website that you can find on the code. My main issue is to successfully logging in. From what I've read online on Google Chrome the technique is to go to Network ->log in -> look at a connection file to get the "formdata". Unfortunately there is no such file. What can I do without using this file ?

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    urls = [
        'https://app.nominations.hospimedia.fr'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        
        # the function "callback" is used after you have logging in
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'email': 'XXX', 'pwd': 'XXXX'},
            callback=self.starts_scraping
        )

    def start_scraping(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//span[@class"name-first-name]/text()"').extract()
        yield {'user_name': name}
```

Alternatively I have also tried with Request but this doesn't work out

```
import scrapy
import json


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    urls = [
        'https://app.nominations.hospimedia.fr'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        payload = {
            'payload': {
                'email': 'XXX',
                'pwd': 'XX',
            }
        }
        
        # the function "callback" is used after you have logging in
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://app.nominations.hospimedia.fr',
            body=json.dumps(payload),
            method='POST',
            callback=self.starts_scraping
        )

    def start_scraping(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//span[@class"name-first-name]/text()"').extract()
        yield {'user_name': name}
```

Comment: I think you should inspect the network for the sent request when logging in by your self you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886372/how-to-crawl-a-website-that-requires-login-using-scrapy#:~:text=You%20can%20manually%20login%20and,duplicate%20it%20in%20your%20scraper.

Comment: I have already looked at the network but the required file with all the information is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `urls` should be `start_urls`.
2. you have a typo in the callback `self.starts_scraping` instead of `self.start_scraping`.

```py
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['https://app.nominations.hospimedia.fr']

    def parse(self, response):
        # the function "callback" is used after you have logging in
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'user[email]': 'XXX', 'user[password]': 'XXXX'},
            callback=self.start_scraping
        )

    def start_scraping(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//span[@class"name-first-name]/text()"').extract()
        yield {'user_name': name}
```

Comment: Actually it is not working I am not logged in in the next page

Comment: @glouis You need to enter the `name` not the `id`. See the edit.

Comment: Yes I have already tried this solution yesterday. Unfortunately it is not working...

Comment: Can I signup so I can check it myself? inside `start_scraping` add in the first line `from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser` and then in the second line `open_in_browser(response)`, and see if you get expected page.

Comment: Well actually it is working maybe I was too tired yesterday and misread, thanks :)

Comment: @glouis Great. No problem!